# Issues when importing a custom module into my MicroPython Pico-W Project

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am very inexperineced and new when it comes to file structures of things like this. I am currently messing around with MicroPython and the Pico-W. I am trying to import a module from another python file but I keep getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: no module named 'foo'`

Currently my file structure looks like this:

```
my-proj:
 - main.py
 - foo.py
```

and my code like this:

```
main.py
________

from foo import bar

bar()
```

```
foo.py
________

def bar():
print('foobar')
```

I have tried moving things in and out of folders, separating them, installing them to the Pico-W, etc. Can't seem to figure it out and I am sure it's simple and I am just blind to it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you in python interpreter? Where you are running `python main.py`?

Comment: this will not work because the indentation in `def bar():` is missing.

Comment: Python requires indentation.  presumably this is a typo....

Comment: How are you uploading the files to the Raspberry Pi Pico, and how are you running them?  Can you post a screenshot so we can verify both files are in the board's file system and both are at the top level?  They should not be a in a folder named `my-proj`, or else you'll have to do extra stuff to get the import to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need go to my-proj first.

```
cd my-proj
python foo.py
```

or add to the environment variables.

```
foo.py
---------
import sys
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = abspath.split(os.sep)[-1]
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
sys.path.append(abspath)
```

Answer (score 0):

On a MicroPython device the `main.py` and `boot.py` files are located in the "root".

Additional files *should* be placed inside the `lib` directory.

```
pyboard/
├── lib
│   ├── foo.py
├── boot.py
├── main.py
```

You can check the MicroPython default sys path with

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

With that you can use this as `main.py`

```py
from foo import bar

bar()
```

and the following as `lib/foo.py`

```py
def bar():
    print('foobar')
```